# Error404 and System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, routes, custom-errors

I'm using Routing in Asp.net 4.0/vb.net as example below:

```
rotas.MapPageRoute("test", "test/{detail}/{id}", "~/test/test.aspx")
```

In web.config has set the customErrors:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.htm" mode="On">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error404.htm"/>
</customErrors>
```

A 404 error page appears correctly if an invalid url is submitted without using routing. Example: site/defaul2.aspx.

But if i enter an invalid url using routing like site/test2/anything/123 appears the standard asp.net 404 error page instead of my 404 custom page (Error404.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS7, you may have to specify your custom error pages there as well.

Click on the site and select "Error Pages" (in IIS list) and change the entry for 404 and 500.

[image]

This wasn't a step I had to do in IIS6, but II6 did require a wildcard handler for URL Routing so ASP.NET handled requests for non-native files (i.e. jpg, png, pdf, etc.).  IIS7 does this by default, but from my experience doesn't push to ASP.NET error pages for those assets - which is why you have to set those error pages explicitly.